# Error when outputting the earth obj in OpenGl

Tags: c++, wavefront

I want to print out the earth obj, but it keeps printing strangely like a picture.

[image]

The vertexes are printed in an empty form in the middle.

`_mesh = new Mesh("obj\\13902_Earth_v1_l3.obj", "obj\\Earth_diff.jpg");`

First, enter the file name like this. Over there, _mesh is the object of the Mesh class that I created.

```cpp
    Mesh(char* obj, char* texture) {
        open(obj);
        loadTexture(texture, _textureIndex);
    }
```

This is the constructor of the Mesh class. The Opne function outputs obj, and loadTexture reads the texture. just look at the Open function.

```cpp
void Mesh::open(char* file)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char buffer[100] = { 0 };
    Vec3<double> pos;
    int index[3], tex[3], empty[3];
    int id = 0;
    _minBound.Set(1000000.0);
    _maxBound.Set(-1000000.0);

    fopen_s(&fp, file, "r");
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %lf %lf %lf", buffer, &pos[0], &pos[1], &pos[2]) != EOF)
    {
        // v 0.2 0.3 0.1
        // vt
        if (buffer[0] == 'v' && buffer[1] == NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (_minBound[i] > pos[i]) _minBound[i] = pos[i];
                if (_maxBound[i] < pos[i]) _maxBound[i] = pos[i];
            }

            _vertices.push_back(new Vertex(id, pos));
        }
    }

    // read texture coordinate of vertics
    id = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %lf %lf", &buffer, &pos[0], &pos[1]) != EOF) {
        if (!strcmp(buffer, "vt")) {
            _textureCoords.push_back(new Texture(pos[0], 1.0 -  pos[1], 0.0));
        }
    }

    // read faces
    id = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", &buffer, &index[0], &tex[0], &empty[0],  &index[1], &tex[1], &empty[1], &index[2], &tex[2], &empty[2]) != EOF) {
        if (buffer[0] == 'f' && buffer[1] == NULL) {
            auto v0 = _vertices[index[0] - 1];
            auto v1 = _vertices[index[1] - 1];
            auto v2 = _vertices[index[2] - 1];
            _faces.push_back(new Face(id++, v0, v1, v2, tex[0] - 1, tex[1] - 1, tex[2] - 1));
            //_faces.push_back(new Face(index++, _vertices[v_index[0] - 1], _vertices[v_index[1] - 1], _vertices[v_index[2] - 1]));

        }
    }


    fclose(fp);

    moveToCenter(10.0);
    makeList();
    computeNormal();

}
```

In the code, _vertices and _faces are class vectors that I've created. It's simply a text file in this format that's made vector computation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I didn't read the value of vn there, and I didn't read the third value of f. Then at least the vertex value would have been entered well, but why does it print out like that?

This is what it looks like when I don't put on textures.

[image]

All other sphere objects are printed in that form. How do we solve this?

Comment: In this case the faces are quads instead of triangles and have 4 indices instead of 3. You need to make 2 triangles for each quad: i[0], i[1], i[2] and i[0], i[2], i[3]

Comment: The same phenomenon occurs even after changing the face part by adding an index. ```_faces.push_back(new Face(id++, v0, v1, v2, v3, tex[0] - 1, tex[1] - 1, tex[2] - 1, tex[3] - 1));```

Comment: Please read your own code. You do not even read the 4th index. `fscanf(fp, "%s %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d"` just reads the 3 indices.

Comment: Of course, I edited it like this. ```while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", &buffer, &index[0], &tex[0], &empty[0], &index[1], &tex[1], &empty[1], &index[2], &tex[2], &empty[2], &index[3], &tex[3], &empty[3]) != EOF)```

Comment: I have also edited the constructor of the face class.

Comment: So it's solved now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it has not been resolved.

Comment: It's my first time studying opengl, so I'm just frustrated.

Comment: First, I find out how to print two obj files on one screen. The goal is to print out the moon orbiting around the Earth

Comment: Oh, it's solved! Thanks a lot. Rabbid76!!!! I'm so grateful to you.